# Get specific column from DataRow without iteration through every column

Tags: c#, dataset

Im new to DataSets and I am trying to get a specific column from a DataSet. I wrote this code

```
using (var dataset = new U2ZFDataSetTableAdapters.stationenTableAdapter())
{
    var ds = new U2ZFDataSet();
    dataset.Fill(ds.stationen);

    var rows = ds.stationen.Select("pdvorhanden = 1");

    foreach (DataRow row in rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn column in ds.stationen.Columns)
        {
            if(column.ColumnName == "Bezeichnung")
                listOfStations.Add(row[column].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The code feels slow to me. Isnt there a better way to do this? How can I get a specific Colum from DataRow without iterating through every column of the row?

Answer (score 0):

Access to the column via column name.

```
foreach (DataRow row in rows)
{
    listOfStations.Add(row["Bezeichnung"].ToString());
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5(v=vs.110).aspx